# Use of the term "Abstract Syntax Tree"

Tags: scala, data-structures, functional-programming, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to further my understanding of Scala, and one thing that has me puzzled is the use of the term *Abstract Syntax Tree* (aka AST).

In many places now I have seen programmers use the term *AST* to describe some code. The following example is from the book *"Advanced Scala"* by Noel Welsh and Dave Gurnell in the section describing the Type Class pattern.

```
// Define a very simple JSON AST
sealed trait Json
final case class JsObject(get: Map[String, Json]) extends Json
final case class JsString(get: String) extends Json
final case class JsNumber(get: Double) extends Json
```

I guess the above is a tree, albeit a very shallow one.

```
                 Json
                  |
      +-----------+-+-----------+
      |             |           |
  JsObject      JsString      JsNumber
```

My understanding of an AST is generally in the context of a compiler which creates an AST from the the Concrete Syntax Tree that represents the code (Code Syntaxt Analysis -> Concrete Syntax Tree -> Abstract Syntax Tree).

Why is the above an AST?

I know that the authors are not using the term in the context of the syntax analysis of a compiler but since AST is generally used to mean an abstract representation of code, why would anyone use the term to describe some actual code?

Comment: Did it say *AST* or **ADT** (algebraic data type)?

Comment: If you view JSON as a language, then parsing its syntax will generate an AST. JSON by definition is a data interchange protocol, but the term language is rather vague so you may, as for your flavor, call it as such.

Comment: AST. Point taken, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not called an AST because of the inheritance tree. It's called an AST because it's a tree structure and it represents the syntax of JSON.

To see how it is a tree structure, consider the following example:

```
{"a": 42, "b": {"x": "y"}}
```

This will be parsed to the following object:

```
JsObject(Map(
    "a" -> JsInt(42),
    "b" -> JsObject(Map(
      "x" -> JsString("y")
    ))
))
```

Which represents the following tree:

```
         Object
    "a" /      \ "b"
      Int    Object
       |        | "x"
       42    String
                |
               "y"
```

This is an abstract syntax tree of the above JSON string.

> I know that the authors are not using the term in the context of the syntax analysis of a compiler

Not of a compiler, but they are using it in the context of analyzing the abstract syntax of JSON.

Comment: It says `JsObject(get: Map[String, Json])` in the definition, I don't think that `JsString` belongs on the left hand side of the arrows. The `String`-valued labels belong rather on the *edges*, they describe the structure of the tree: that's the whole point of semi-structured data. But then it also depends on how "abstract" you want your "abstract syntax tree", nothing prevents anyone from having multiple ASTs of different levels of abstraction...